# How does $\neg \phi$ as $\phi \to \textbf{false}$ fit in intuitionist philosophy?

Tags: type-theory, intuitionistic-logic

In intuitionist type theory that I know, $\neg \phi$ is interpreted as a function that takes a proof of $\phi$ and outputs a proof of **false**.

It seems to me that this is different from the way that classical logicians think of $\neg \phi$. They simply think of it as "not $\phi$", and then think of "$\phi \to \textbf{false}$" as a **proof** of "not $\phi$".

It seems to me that inuitionist logic is kind of "sneaking an axiom" into the logic by defining $\neg \phi$ as $\phi \to \textbf{false}$, namely the axiom that $(\phi \to \textbf{false})\to \neg \phi$. From my perspective, this should really be seen as a logical axiom, not as a definition of $\neg \phi$.

If you accept that view, then it seems to me that the difference between "proof of negation" and "proof by contradiction" explained in [this article](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/) becomes less hard.

**So how does $\neg \phi \leftrightarrow (\phi\to \textbf{false}) $ fit within the intuitionist philosophy? How is this justified?**

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I already stated that in my question.

Comment: Well how do you define "not $\phi$" as anything else but "there is no way to make $\phi$ work : look if it did the world would crumble down into $\bot$-ness" ?

Comment: More seriously, intuitionistically, there is no truth or falsehood, only provability and refutability. Now to say $\neg \phi$ is to refute $\phi$. Now think about how you can prove a negative statement (in real life and in maths)

Comment: @Max, here are two ways to prove negative statements: 1: in real life: take the statement "it is not raining outside". look outside and see that it isn't raining. Q.E.D. (no function to $\bot$ was involved). 2. in math: Assume $Q \to \neg P \land Q$. conclude $\neg P$ by modus ponens.

Comment: Seriously though, these comments don't really answer my confusion. I am simply not seeing how this assumption fits cleanly in intuitionist philosophy.

Comment: In your first example, you precisely used something that intuitionist philosophy does not recognize : a notion of truth. You didn't prove that it wasn't raining, you observed the falsehood of the statement that it's raining. And your second example doesn't make sense because well you haven't proved $\neg P$ you proved $(Q\land (Q\implies Q\land \neg P))\implies \neg P$. When there is no notion of truth $\neg P$ cannot be defined as a primitive, because there is no sensible interpretation for "not" in terms of proofs